# add hostname mappings using --add-host parameter not working for scratch image

Tags: docker

Add `hostname` mappings using the `--add-host` parameter is not working for a scratch image.

I configure it as following:

```
extra_hosts:
  - "op.swish-cloud.com:10.170.0.2"
```

But the actual id of requests from the container is the external internet ip of `op.swish-cloud.com` rather than `10.170.0.2`

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]?  When you say "scratch" do you mean the special Docker `FROM scratch` empty image or something else?

Comment: Any docker image base on scratch image@DavidMaze

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone ends up here from a Google search, this is going to be expected behavior. You need to mount a file as `/etc/hosts` or at least make sure the file exists in order for `--add-host` to work in the scratch image.